# Conditional formatting formula removal not working

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formula

I have a worksheet with conditional formatting.  I need to remove the conditional formulas, but when I do and they are gone, I save the sheet, exit, and re-load the sheet.  When I check, the formulas are back.  How can I get rid of them permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are removing rules from some selected cells. You can remove conditional formatting rules from entire sheet. See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I tried this before but formulas keep returning.